# how to get parse url in google map to get the details about location and neighbourhood in android

Tags: android, json, dictionary

here is my code

```
public static JSONObject getLocationInfo(String address) {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                try {

               // address = address.replaceAll(" ","%20");    

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false");
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;
                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


                    response = client.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                    int b;
                    while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                        stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return jsonObject;
            }
```

I am getting a json exception , at the response . please tell me a valid url . Also I did mapview (api key and android manifest permission) for gps.

Logcat:

```
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202): java.net.UnknownHostException: android.clients.google.com
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:248)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at com.google.android.common.http.GoogleHttpClient.executeWithoutRewriting(GoogleHttpClient.java:203)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at com.google.android.common.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(GoogleHttpClient.java:245)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at com.google.android.common.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(GoogleHttpClient.java:313)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at com.google.android.gsf.checkin.CheckinTask.sendRequest(CheckinTask.java:254)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at com.google.android.gsf.checkin.CheckinTask.doInBackground(CheckinTask.java:150)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at com.google.android.gsf.checkin.CheckinService$1.doInBackground(CheckinService.java:221)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at com.google.android.gsf.checkin.CheckinService$1.doInBackground(CheckinService.java:214)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
04-03 16:35:20.548: E/CheckinTask(202):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: paste your error log for reference the url is correct to fetch all the address matching the given string

Comment: @divaNilisha, refer this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingResponses and it is helpful to us that you post your logcat.

Comment: how to put the logcat error here instead of comment, sorry i am new to it .

Comment: please have some trouble to look at it , i am new to it

Comment: response = client.execute(httppost);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private String getJSONFile(String URL) {
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
        int c;
        while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) c);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: which method you are talking about?

Comment: i am still having unknown host exception

Comment: Are you running your app in the emulator or device?

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I can see two main issues:

1. You are not formatting the url to account for spaces and other non-url friendly characters.
2. You are using a POST instead of a GET

As for number one, above, you can do this manually, or you can have it handled through java's [URI class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html).

As for number two, above, you are also using the wrong method to call the URL. You should be using [HttpGet](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) instead of HttpPost.

You can test this out by using curl:

```
curl -X POST 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20NW,%20Washington,%20DC&sensor=false'
```

The POST call above will give you and error, where as the GET method will not:

```
curl -X GET 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20NW,%20Washington,%20DC&sensor=false'
```

Also, instead of using string builder to read the body contents, I find using apache's own [IOUtil's class](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) to be easier and more straightforward.

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(response.getEntity().getContent(), writer);
```

However, you would have to import the library.

Finally, make sure you have given internet permission in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

create URL like this,

```
String address = "yagnik+road,+rajkot";
```

and pass this below url to intent

```
http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=+address
```