# Google place API for android to find city

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have seen the tutorial( [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/maps/places/autocomplete-android) ) to find the city using autocomplete text view in android.i have done everything that is instructed but now when i hit [this url](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?sensor=false&key=API_KEY&input=sa)

it always throws me an exception saying :  `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "maps.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname`

but the same url work fine when i hit through browser and i am getting the results also.

Here is the code i m hitting with :

```
public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter< String > implements Filterable{
 private ArrayList<String> resultList;
 private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

 private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
 private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
 private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

 private static final String API_KEY = "I have generated the correct api key also";


public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resultList.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
    return resultList.get(index);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
              FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
             if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
        }
    };
    return filter;
}

private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
    //   sb.append("&components=country:in");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
      // sb.append("&input=" + input);

       System.out.println("URL ---------------: "+sb.toString());
        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

}

---

oops! sorry guys. 
I have found the solution that was a silly mistake.I had not defined the INTERNET permission in the manifest.

Comment: I also face this issue and found answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991616/how-to-get-parse-url-in-google-map-to-get-the-details-about-location-and-neighbo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check if you have added INTERNET permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I have added this permission then also i got same Error, Is there any Problem in Emulator

Comment: Always user real device for google map, phone calls , sms, mms, location testing.

Comment: I have added the permission in my Manifest file.. I'm using my phone as testing device and i'm well connected to wifi... yet the problem persists... can you help? @neo

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me today. I figured it out by following these steps:
1: Check that you add the INTERNET permission in manifest.

2: Make sure that your laptop or the device you are testing your app on could access the internet.

FYI, as for the key for places API, you should use "**Key for browser apps (with referers)**", not the Key for Android apps.

Good luck.