# Android:Google Maps v2 grey screen and get UnknownHostException for geocoding

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-geocoding-api

I'm making an app, in it, there will be some addresses generated and I need to show these addresses on a Google map. I would use HttpGet with google API for geocoding with this URL

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=my_address&sensor=true_or_false
```

with myaddress replaced with the addresses generated. The whole thing was working perfectly and all of a sudden both the google maps and the geocoding doesn't work. The maps just displays the grey tiled screen and the httpGet gives an error as follows:

```
06-05 06:10:15.047: W/System.err(4432): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "maps.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
06-05 06:10:15.077: W/System.err(4432):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
06-05 06:10:15.077: W/System.err(4432):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
06-05 06:10:15.087: W/System.err(4432):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
06-05 06:10:15.087: W/System.err(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
06-05 06:10:15.087: W/System.err(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-05 06:10:15.097: W/System.err(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-05 06:10:15.097: W/System.err(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-05 06:10:15.097: W/System.err(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-05 06:10:15.107: W/System.err(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-05 06:10:15.107: W/System.err(4432):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-05 06:10:15.107: W/System.err(4432):     at com.example.tradeapp.JSONConnectorGet.connectClient(JSONConnectorGet.java:53)
06-05 06:10:15.107: W/System.err(4432):     at com.example.tradeapp.MapViewingActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MapViewingActivity.java:74)
06-05 06:10:15.107: W/System.err(4432):     at com.example.tradeapp.MapViewingActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MapViewingActivity.java:1)
06-05 06:10:15.107: W/System.err(4432):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-05 06:10:15.107: W/System.err(4432):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-05 06:10:15.107: W/System.err(4432):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-05 06:10:15.107: W/System.err(4432):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-05 06:10:15.107: W/System.err(4432):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-05 06:10:15.107: W/System.err(4432):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-05 06:10:15.107: W/System.err(4432): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
06-05 06:10:15.127: W/System.err(4432):     at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
06-05 06:10:15.127: W/System.err(4432):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
06-05 06:10:15.127: W/System.err(4432):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
06-05 06:10:15.127: W/System.err(4432):     ... 18 more
```

I haven't changed anything and now it doesn't work. I tried changing Goggle API key in the console and tried again, still same results.

I found that we should send API key as well in httpGet, so I tried with

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=my_address&sensor=true_or_false&key=my_key
```

(It worked perfectly fine without the key in the url before), and still no results.

Any way to fix?

Here is android manifest (which is the same as it was when it worked, of course with API key changed several times but with still no results)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tradeapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.tradeapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA4egtZQUMDjJtTOiy94K2CCh22glrZjT0" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tradeapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tradeapp.BackendProcessViewingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_backend_process_viewing"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.tradeapp.OptionsActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="OptionsActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tradeapp.OptionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_options"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.tradeapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tradeapp.ShipmentEventFindingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_shipment_event_finding"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.tradeapp.ShipmentSearchingActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="ShipmentSearchingActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tradeapp.ShipmentSearchingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_shipment_searching"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.tradeapp.OptionsActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.tradeapp.OptionsActivity" />
        </activity>



        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tradeapp.MapViewingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_viewing"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.tradeapp.ShipmentEventFindingActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.tradeapp.ShipmentEventFindingActivity" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Has your network changed? Perhaps on the new network (another wifi, another ISP?) the DNS entry to maps.googleapis.com is blocked or anything like that?

Comment: @dermatthias, nope everything was the same and then after an hour or so it just started working again. I'm completely clueless as to why this happened.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google place API for android to find city](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195382/google-place-api-for-android-to-find-city)